# Mutually independent $P(A ∩ B ∩ C) \ne P(A ∩ B∩ A ∩ C)$

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

I have events $A$, $B$, $C$ which are mutually independent. Let's say $A∩B$ and $A∩C$ are also independent. Then $$P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(A)P(B)P(C)$$ but
$$P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = P((A ∩ B) ∩ (A ∩ C)) = P(A ∩ B)P(A ∩ C) = P(A)P(B)P(A)P(C)$$
$$P(A)P(B)P(C) = P(A)P(B)P(A)P(C)$$

Why is it so? I guess that $A = \Omega$ or $\emptyset$? How then this conclusion can be drawn from given properties? Would really appreciate any input.

Comment: Who said $A\cap B$ and $A\cap C$ are independent?

Comment: @RushabhMehta That's given.

Comment: No? You said $A,B,C$ are independent.

Comment: Also, what about $B \cap C$ being independent events?

Comment: @LiveFreeorπHard they are mutually independent, so by definition it is so.

Comment: @RushabhMehta A∩B A∩C are independended, that's stated in question.

Comment: If that's the case, then $P(A)=0$.

Comment: @RushabhMehta or P(A)=1. But why? Can this conclusion be drawn any other way?

Comment: $P(A)=0$ or $P(A)=1$ does not imply that $A=\varnothing$ or $A=\Omega$.

Comment: @Zvi really? That's interesting, why is that?

Comment: Take $\Omega=\Bbb{R}$ for example, say, with the standard normal distribution.  Then, $A=\{0\}$ is not empty but $P(A)=0$.    Similarly, $A=\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$ is not $\Omega$ but $P(A)=1$.

Comment: @Zvi I guess it is, thank you. But i wonder is A=∅ or A=Ω in this problem?

Comment: I don't know.  What is $\Omega$ here?  What is the probability distribution on $\Omega$?  If we don't know these two pieces of information, I'm afraid you cannot conclude $A=\varnothing $or $A=\Omega$.

Comment: @Zvi well it is arbitrary. Actually I am trying to poof other thing, but this got in the way. I think it is wierd.